# Заполнение Select списком файлов из папки с группировкой

Tags: javascript, select

Подскажите как организовать заполнение с группировкой объекта Select списком файлов из папки (допустим .data/device/).
Сейчас заполнение выполняется так:

```html
<section>
  <select id="select_" class="cs-select cs-skin-overlay">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Выберите весы</option>
    <optgroup label="Блок 1">
      <option value="tenzo 1-1">Весы 1-1</option>
      <option value="tenzo 1-2">Весы 1-2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Блок 2">
      <option value="tenzo 2-1">Весы 2-1</option>
      <option value="tenzo 2-2">Весы 2-2</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</section>
```

В папке файлы вида tenzo **1**-1.txt , tenzo **1**-2.txt , tenzo 2-1.txt и т.д.
Группировка в блоки optgroup должна происходить по признаку первой цифры после слова "tenzo".  Т.е. если например после слова "tenzo" стоит цифра = **1**, то создается optgroup label="Блок (и здесь цифра, в данном случае **1**)"
спасибо.

Comment: Какой инструмент для чтения файлов используете или вы уже получили и не знаете как сделать select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебирает массив файлов files через forEach, делает объект групп groups и тут работает с DOM.

```js
const files = ['tenzo 1-1.txt', 'tenzo 2-1.txt', 'tenzo 1-2.txt', 'tenzo 1-3.txt', 'tenzo 2-2.txt']
const groups = {}

var sel = document.createElement("select");

files.forEach(i => {
  let optgroup
  const group = +i.match(/\d+/)
  const opt = document.createElement('option')
  opt.text = i
  opt.value = i
  
  if (!groups[group]) {
    optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup')
    optgroup.label = 'Блок ' + group
    
    sel.add(optgroup)
  
    groups[group] = []
    groups[group].optgroup = optgroup
  }
  
  if (!groups[group])
    sel.add(opt)
  else
    groups[group].optgroup.appendChild(opt)
  
  groups[group].push(i)
})

document.querySelector('#wrap').appendChild(sel)
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, то что надо. Как получить список файлов тоже пока не понял.

Comment: это надо с сервера получать, например через php. Можете сделать через ajax запрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Да только все это в новинку, единственный язык который я знаю - VBA. пока даже не понимаю как правильно гуглить на эту тему